# How to read from dictionary?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
static Dictionary<String ^, List<String ^>^> ^ language_string_table;
```

Where I have 17 `string`s. For each of 17 `string`s there is an associated list of 1500 `string`s. Now what i want to do is: compare strings in all the lists at each and every index.

e.x. 1st list 1st element should be compared with all the list's 1st element. Similarly for all the indexes in all the lists.

Comment: Does C++ has `Dictionary` type?

Comment: vc++ has. I am working on Visual Studio 2008. I need .Net solution

Comment: For example: Its like name of the class which contains list of all the members of the class. First string is class name and the list associated with that is members of the class.

Comment: In reference to the above example i stated, i need to compare each and member of each class according to their index. To be more precise each and every class member should be compared based on their index in the class

Comment: Visual C++ allows you to write both: Standard C++ and [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) (and even the obsolete [Managed C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_Extensions_for_C%2B%2B)). You are using C++/CLI (the one with all that `ref class`, `^` and `gcnew`). To avoid future confusion you should tag your questions not with _VisualC++_ or _C++_ but with _C++-CLI_.

Comment: Ok done. got it. Next time i will take care that this wont happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use loops?

```
    for each(KeyValuePair<String^ , List<String^>^> pair1 in qwe)
    {
        for each(KeyValuePair<String^ , List<String^>^> pair2 in qwe) 
        {
            if(! pair1.Key->Equals(pair2.Key))
            {
                for(int i = 0; i< 1500; ++i)
                {
                    SomeCompareFunction(pair1.Value[i],pair2.Value[i]) 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can compare 2 Lists with [`Enumerable::SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx):

```
List<String^>^ list1 = ...;
List<String^>^ list2 = ...;
bool equal = Enumerable::SequenceEqual(list1, list2);
```

You only have to iterate over the dictionary values and compare it as above.